Does the value of a limit change if a choose a different kind of neighborhood?
Let $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function over an interval $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R$. Let $x_0\in\Omega\setminus\partial\Omega$. By the usual definition of limit, we can say that
$$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\ell\in\mathbb R \iff \forall\varepsilon>0\,\exists\delta>0:0<|x-x_0|<\delta\implies|f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$$
So we are choosing the neighborhood $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ for $x_0$ and $(\ell-\varepsilon,\ell+\varepsilon)$ for $\ell$. My question is, can I choose different neighborhoods without affecting the value of the limit? For instance, can I choose $(x_0-\delta,x_0+2\delta)$, or $(\ell-3\varepsilon,\ell+5\varepsilon)$?

You are still dealing with the same kind of "neighborhood" (open intervals that include $x$ and $f(x)$ in the interior). You get the same limit because for each nbd of the usual type, you can find an nbd of the "new" type completely included in it, and vice versa.

You can always scale. If for example, you discovered that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ so that $x\in(x_0-\frac 12\delta, x_0 +2\delta)\implies f(x)\in(l-3\epsilon, l+5\epsilon)$ we can let $\epsilon' =\frac 15\epsilon$ and $\delta$ associated with the new $\epsilon'$.  And let $\delta' = \frac 12\delta$ and we are good. $x\in(x_0-\delta',x_0+\delta')=(x_0-\frac12\delta,x_0+\frac12\delta)\subset(x_0-\frac12\delta,x_0+2\delta)\implies f(x)\in(l-3\epsilon',l+5\epsilon')=(1-\frac35\epsilon,l+\epsilon)\subset(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$. We're good.

The limit only depends on topology not on the choice of metric determining the topology.
